# Select range from multiple sheet and export to a single pdf

Tags: vba, pdf, excel

I read this solution to combine sheets to one pdf from another post:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"C:\tempo.pdf", Quality:= xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

However for me it prints out the whole sheet. How do I select the ranges to print for each sheet when I am combining multiple sheets.

I can do it if I export each sheet to a single pdf each but am not sure how to if I were to combine them.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `1` Create a new sheet. `2` Export the relevant ranges from different sheet into this sheet `3` create pdf.

Comment: Is it possible to add a page break between the ranges if I do it this way?

Comment: Tried your solution. However I just realised that the sheets have different cell sizes so the format would be wrong for all but one.

Comment: Then the only alternative that I can think of is to create separate pdf and then merge them?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by creating a sheets array and then navigating through each sheet to select desired ranges. once done use Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF to generate pdf

Sub test()
Sample Code:

```
Sub test()
 Sheets(Array("A", "B")).Select
 Sheets("A").Activate
 Range("A1:J32").Select
 Sheets("B").Activate
 Range("A6:J37").Select
 Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
 Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Test.pdf", _
 Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```